# Umgangssprache für «on second thought»

Tags: word-choice, english-to-german, phrase, colloquial

Gibt es eine einfache, deutsche Art zu «on second thought»? Beispiele:

> 1. Ich möchte das Bargeld in kleinen Noten haben; [on second thought], es wäre besser, wenn ich *grosse* Noten haben könnte.
> 2. Fahren wir morgen Abend um 7 Uhr; [on second thought], morgen habe ich viel zu tun, und bin nicht sicher, ob ich am Abend Zeit haben werde.

Man kann natürlich *nach nochmaliger Überlegung* oder Varianten davon sagen. Ich finde aber, dass sie für die Umgangssprache ein bisschen zu schwerfällig sind. Habe ich Unrecht?

Comment: Übrigens, Ihr dürft gerne mein Deutsch korrigieren.

Comment: Das ist stark von den Personen abhängig ;). Teilweise werden auch einfache Laute verwendet (ah, bspw.), um so etwas auszudrücken. Es kommt eben darauf an *wie* umgangssprachlich gewünscht ist.

Comment: "Beim zweiten Nachdenken" ist zwar einen Deut länger als "on second thought", aber eckige Klammern sind m.E. der Gipfel der Schwerfälligkeit. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eine Möglichkeit ist

> Hab mir's anders überlegt.

oder

> Wissen Sie was, [*optional* hab mir's anders überlegt] ...

auch

> Jetzt, wo ich drüber nachdenke, ...

Eine sehr kurze Variante:

> Obwohl, *[kleine Pause]* ach ...

Comment: +1 "Obwohl" ist mein Favorit. An zweiter Stelle "Wissen Sie was" (ohne Zusatz). Ich benutze oft: "Oder vielleicht..."

Comment: 3 und 4 stimme ich zu. - 1 und 2 sagt man eher, wenn man erst verneint hat und dann sich denkt: *Ach was soll's, es schadet ja nicht.* Passen also beide im Kontext nicht. Bsp.: "Kommst du mit? - Nein. Wobei... weißt du was, ich komme doch mit."

Comment: Neben "obwohl" benutze ich auch oft "andererseits".

Comment: Neben "obwohl" hört man auch: "Wobei, *[kleine Pause]* …"

Comment: Kann _[on second thought]_ durch _obwohl_ in den Beispielen in der originalen Frage ersetzt werden?

Comment: _Wissen Sie was_ finde ich schön. Ist es formeller als _obwohl_? Passt vielleicht besser zu Beispiel Nr. 1.

Comment: Es reicht auch ein "Ach was" oder "Oder, nee:"

Comment: ... beziehungsweise: "Recht bedacht ...".

Comment: Hihi, *Recht bedacht* gefällt mir. Klingt allerdings schon ziemlich gestelzt und würde wohl von vielen gar nicht verstanden werden.

Comment: @TheStochasticShaver: *[on second thought]* kann in beiden Beispielen sehr gut durch *obwohl* ersetzt werden. Ich würde es auch gegenüber *[Wissen Sie was]* vorziehen, denn das ist sehr vom Typ abhängig und kann leicht etwas forsch klingen. Andererseits bezieht es das Gegenüber ins Gespräch ein. Ist das Gespräch eher freundlich/entspannt, passt *[Wissen Sie was]* besser, als wenn das Gespräch eher anonym ist, z.B. in Eile gegenüber einem Bankangestellten.

Comment: @Mrmfldmn: Danke schön.

Comment: @Mrmfldmn: Recht bedacht würde ich dann auch eher zu "beziehungsweise" tendieren. :)

Answer (score 8):

- wenn ich es mir genau überlege
- obwohl
- eigentlich

Answer (score 7):

Die Antworten von splatte sind alle sehr gut und auch das in den Kommentaren genannte andererseits.
Ich möchte jedoch ein weiteres Wort in den Ring werfen:

**eigentlich**

Zusammen mit **ach** oder **hmmm** kann es so verwendet werden wie **on second thought**.